# Calling an ActionResult from view in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new in programming and in Mvc. I have created an ActionResult. I want to call that from view. My code in following.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("a");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.Actionlink

For example,

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")